# How to push values from a multiple select dropdown to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

I am trying to push values into an array from a multiple select dropdown box. I am able to do that but what happens is that they are not pushed into the array in the order i set it up to via splice. It is added in the order it is set up on the select box. For example if i select the options in the order of [467, 341, 344, 657, 677], my array shows [344, 467, 677, 341, 657]. I want the array to show in order I have selected the options.
This is my code:

```
<select multiple class="yo">
    <option value = "344">opt1</option>
    <option value = "467">opt2</option>
    <option value = "677">opt3</option>
    <option value = "341">opt1</option>
    <option value = "657">opt1</option>
</select>

var optVal = new Array();
        var tArray;
        $('.yo').each(function() {
            var newS = $(this).val(); 
            tArray = newS;
            optVal.splice(0, 0, tArray);

        });
```

Please help!

Here is my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rprakash/e1xcd2gh/

Comment: Why not just use `.push()`? It seems like you are using an event handler, please show us in the code and provide a runnable example. I cannot get those results with your code.

Comment: I have added a fiddle!

Comment: Firstly you are not really "pushing" anything to the array, just keeping a single value. Also the multi-select dose not keep track in which order you selected the items, it selects all the items between your two clicks, and does so in a top-down fashion.

Comment: i didnt use push hoping to always add the value at the beginning of the array, i.e. at the index of 0... Push did the same thing what my code above is doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wanted the values inside the `select`, disregarding order, you could use:

```
$(".yo").val()
```

However, you want them order which is much tricker:

```
var optVal = [];
var tempVal = [];

$(".yo").change(function() {

    $(".yo option").each(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var tempVal = $(".yo").val();

        if(tempVal.indexOf(val) >= 0 && optVal.indexOf(val) < 0) {
            optVal.push(val);
        } else if(tempVal.indexOf(val) < 0 && optVal.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
            optVal.splice(optVal.indexOf(val) , 1);
        }

    })
    console.log("Opt: " + optVal);
})
```

- When values have changed, trigger
- Iterate through each `option` and get the value
- Get all selected values from the `select`
- If option is selected and not in `optVal` then push to `optVal`
- If option is not selected and inside `optVal` then remove from optVal

This will keep them in the order they have been selected.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/theblindprophet/pen/RRrJXG?editors=1010

Comment: Great! This works! I have a question though... What if I want every element I select next I want it to go to the index 0. So everytime I select an option I want that value at index 0

Comment: `optVal.unshift(val);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var optVal = new Array();

$('option').click(function() {
  optVal.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: I have tried this. I didnt get any result. Thank you though

Comment: @rashmeePrakash hmm, I wonder why it didn't work. Here is a fiddle of it with a live version https://jsfiddle.net/h98sLubr/

Comment: No worries, one thing that might make it fail sometimes is using the .click() function form of jquery vs the .on("click", function(){}). the .on method is a bit more versatile, and can be bound after the event is added.